# PostgreSQL vs MySQL simple query performance

Tags: mysql, performance, postgresql

I am working in a new web application. I have used MySQL for web application. But now I am studying the PostgreSQL option. 
I did a simple performance test and I noticed PostgreSQL is slower than MySQL.

When you make a website/web application you need to handle with a number of initialization queries each request.
My tests:

```
PgSQL
30000 pgsql execs - 73.53459s
30000 pgsql execs - 88.41614s
30000 pgsql execs - 75.76565s
-----------------------------
Average             79.23879s
378 queries per second or ~2.6 ms per query

MySQL
30000 mysql execs - 22.19208s
30000 mysql execs - 17.81079s
30000 mysql execs - 23.30936s
-----------------------------
Average             21,10407s 
~1421 query per second or ~0.7 ms per query
```

MySQL run ~4x faster than PostgreSQL. **Is it normal? Can't I use PostgreSQL to web application (SAAS) with a lot of connections?**

*Another test I did with concurrent access left me very worried.

Code of test 
(both equal and the teste table just have 2 records and a id_teste index):

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO('pgsql:host=127.0.0.1 dbname=teste user=postgres password=123456');

  $t = 30000;
  $ini = microtime(true);
  for ($i=0;$i<$t;$i++)
  {
    $ex = $db->prepare('select * from teste where id_teste = 1');
    $ex->execute();
  }
  $end = microtime(true);
  echo '<b>'. $t .'</b> pgsql execs - <b>'. number_format($end-$ini,5,'.','') .'</b>s';
?>
```

**Update:** MySQL table engine is Innodb. Both tests in the same device. 
I made a new test with mysqli_query and pg_query and the results were better:

```
30000 pgsql execs - 28.18265s
30000 pgsql execs - 23.54120s
30000 pgsql execs - 23.43689s
Average             25,05358s
~1197 queries per second or ~0,8 ms per query


30000 mysql execs - 23.89033s
30000 mysql execs - 19.40293s
30000 mysql execs - 27.75116s
Average             23,68147s
~1266 queries per second or ~0,79 ms per query
```

Maybe PDO pgsql driver is the problem as was commented or mysqli is slow.

About other options to simple query, like cache, yes it is a option, but it have many simple queries in a big tables and these data need to be stored in a RDBMS. Example: Cities, people, users, pages. All of them used just where id = X. Despite of with more work we could handle this.

Comment: What is the table types on mysql ?

Comment: I can not imagine any web application that only executes this (!) very simple query on an (almost) empty table. If performance matters, why introducing overhead like PDO?

Comment: Toy microbenchmark. If you want nothing but super fast performance on trivial queries, use a K/V store not a RDBMS. Typically you use something like Redis as a caching layer, then the RDBMS for persistent and robust storage and analytics.

Comment: Indeed try without PDO. A query like that executes in a fraction of a millisecond. All the rest is overhead in PHP. The C++ application I'm working would have the result of a query like that on a local db server in less then 100 microseconds.

Comment: Your tests are really worthless (no offence). You might as well measure the time of covering 10 meters by a locomotive pulling a baby carriage.

Comment: So the difference between PostgreSQL and MySQL using pg_functions and mysql_functions is on average 0.01 millisecond in this "test". Any bitfart of your computer can cause a difference like this. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Frank, the differences are in prepare method, the second test with mysqli_query vs pg_query is just to add another view.

Comment: Klin, I am very worried with performance. A small exec with a few queries using prepare method take 100ms more in postgresql than mysql (same code). 100ms is too much for web. But the good news is the problem is with "prepare", if I use direct "exec($stmt)" pgsql is faster like mysql. I will continue investigating...

Comment: Are you going to have more than 100 queries per _second_?  If not, then it does not matter which you pick.  If so, then you need to look into tuning the engine to work better.  Either way, you cannot really pick between MySQL and Postgres with any degree of certainty.

Comment: Your prepare-statement is done within the loop, you prepare the same statement 30000 times. And when using the pg-functions, you could also use pg_prepare() to prepare a query. PDO is just overhead and only makes sense when supporting many different databases. But in that case an ORM makes even more sense. PHP + PostgreSQL is lightning fast, unless you make it slow.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on lot of factors - table size, indexes, engines in MySQL, OS.

For these ultra simple queries Postgres can be slower than MySQL - PostgreSQL has richer planner, that works better on more complex queries, but on trivial queries is slower.

But in your example the strong factors can be speed of PDO driver too. Other question is if you are use pooling connections or not. Without pooling connections the overhead of connect is larger then query execution. For fast queries some solution like pgbouncer, pgpool is necessary.

In real world the real bottleneck are speed of IO and SQL planner quality. But your test doesn't check anything from it.

Comment: The connection is made only once, doesn't matter in this "test" if you use a connection pool or not. But you do need one :-)